# Making a scrollable gtk.TreeView without using a gtk.ScrolledWindow

Tags: python, scroll, treeview, gtk

I made a TreeView to select an item from a [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvQfr.png) that depends on other selections. Because the list is variable (long or short), I want to add a vertical scrollbar. I've searched  how to do this, but all the answers that I found use a ScrolledWindow. Is there another way to do this?

My code is here:

```
import gtk
```

[...]

```
screen = gtk.Fixed()
```

[...]

```
treeView = gtk.TreeView()
treeView.connect("row-activated", self.on_activated_seq1)
# Items de los IDs (IDs disponibles, inicialmente vacio)
self.store_ids = gtk.ListStore(str)
self.store_ids.append(["----------------------"])
treeView.set_model(self.store_ids)
# Columnas 
rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Secuencias\nDisponibles", rendererText, text=0)
treeView.append_column(column)
treeView.set_headers_visible(False)
treeView.set_enable_search(True)
```

[...]

```
screen.put(treeView, 50,200) # treeView IDs
```

Comment: And why doesn't a ScrolledWindow work? The proper answer depends on your actual goal. Explain a bit please.

Comment: I want to create a list whose filling depends on the selection of 2 Comboboxes, so I want these 3 (the Comboboxes and the list) to be in the same window. So far I have managed to put the Comboboxes and the list in the same window, and I have also solved the filling of the list. But I do not know how to add a scroll bar to the list. I understand that with the ScrolledWindow a subwindow is created but I do not want to create a new one.

Comment: `ScrolledWIndow` does not create a separate window; you can add it to your main window just as you can with every other widget. But maybe it was different with the older version of Gtk.